# Free up phone memory taken up by thumbnails

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, external-sd, photos, thumbnails

I have a 16 GB Samsung Galaxy S3 phone - 5.05GB of which is being taken up by thumbnails! Can I move these to my 32GB SD card?

I have tried DMR (duplicate media remover) and that has detected duplicate pics and videos but stops when I try to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [clean master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard) to free up your space.
In particular, to delete your thumbnails, follow these steps:

- Install [clean master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard) on your phone.
- Open it and click on "start".
- Tap "advanced" on the right top.
- Wait for the app section to load, then tap "gallery".
- Tap "Gallery thumbnails".
- Select all items by checking the box on the top right.
- Tap "clean".
- Tap "clean" again in the confirmation box.

Please note that, after you have deleted your thumbnails, previews of the photos in the gallery will take longer to load the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an app like [Es File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)

It has a SD Card Analyze tool, which will help you analyze the total space used and give you options to clear some space by deleting unused files, temp file etc.

For the issue with thumbnails, take a backup of all your photos on Google Photos.. then delete all the thumbnails.. deleting thumbnails will not delete the images.. Even if it does delete, you will still have the backup in Google Photos.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a SD card then you can quickly root your device (https://kingroot.net/) and apply a setting which sees your SD card as internal memory rather than external memory which allows you to put all applications onto it(This setting is included in the root). But you need to be careful as this will burn up the SD card over time so just try to keep data on the card rather than applications so you don't end up booting from the card all the time.